# Java regex split string with dashes and space

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like:

```
String t = "this is my--test string";
```

I need to split it by space and -- So i tried:

```
String[] m = t.split("[\\s -]");
```

It returns

```
["this", "is", "my", "", "test", "string"]
```

but in reality i needed

```
["this", "is", "my", "--", "test", "string"]
```

What am I missing? is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
String[] result = t.split("\\s+|(?<=--)(?!-)|(?<!-)(?=--)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w9yQVa/2/). *Details*:

- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `(?<=--)(?!-)` - a location immediately preceded with `--` and not immediately followed with `-`
- `|` - or
- `(?<-)(?=--)` - a location not immediately preceded with `-` and  immediately followed with `--`.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/WMd8kY):

```java
String regex = "\\s+|(?<=--)(?!-)|(?<!-)(?=--)";
String string = "this is my--test string";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(string.split(regex)));
// => [this, is, my, --, test, string]
```

Comment: @saka1029deleted The `\b` word boundary is a zero-width assertion, and splitting with `\b` results in additional matches before and after words.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, just curious, is there anything wrong with just using the 2 positive look ahead/behinds like so? `\s+|(?=--)|(?<=--)`  Why the need to pair up a negative with the positive?

Comment: @Daniel Thank you for drawing attention. I think the pattern should look like `\s+|(?<=--)(?!-)|(?<!-)(?=--)`. The counter-lookarounds are necessary to avoid splitting in the middle of the hyphen chunk. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/w9yQVa/2) vs. [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/w9yQVa/3).

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to do it with just regex but does this work?

```
String t = "this is my--test string";
t = t.replace( "--", " -- " );
String[] m = t.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex matcher to do this:

```java
public static void main (String[] args) {
    final String t = "this is my--test string";
    
    final String regex = "(-+)|(\\w+)";
    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(t);

    List<String> split = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        split.add(matcher.group(0));
    }

    System.out.println(split);
}
```

The regex explanation:

- `(-+)`: matches the character "-" one or multiple times;
- `|`: equivalent to boolean OR;
- `(\\w+)`: matches any word character (equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) one or multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want and is slightly simpler than the earlier answer (which also works).

`String[] m = t.split("\\s+|\\-\\-");`